# Using Mockito with TestNG

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, testng

I took a working test written for JUnit using Mockito and tried to adapt it to work with TestNG but oddly using TestNG only one test will work.

I think it is somehow related to the resetting of the mocks but I have played around with trying to call Mockito.reset and using BeforeMethod and BeforeClass and different combinations but still can only get one test to pass.

What I need to do to get the test to work?

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {       
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);                                
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(calculatorController).build();
}

@AfterMethod
public void reset() {
    Mockito.reset(calculatorService);
}

@Test
public void addFunctionTest() throws Exception {             
    Assert.assertNotNull(calculatorController);
     Result expectedResult = new Result();
     expectedResult.setResult(10);

    when(calculatorService.add(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(expectedResult);                             

    mockMvc.perform(get("/calculator/add").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .param("val1", "100")
            .param("val2", "100"))  
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result", equalTo(10)));    

    verify(calculatorService, times(1)).add(anyInt(), anyInt());
}   

@Test
public void subtractFunctionTest() throws Exception {            
    Assert.assertNotNull(calculatorController);
    Result expectedResult = new Result();
    expectedResult.setResult(90);

    when(calculatorService.subtract(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(expectedResult);                                

    mockMvc.perform(get("/calculator/subtract").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .param("val1", "100")
    .param("val2", "10"))  
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result", equalTo(90)));    

    verify(calculatorService, times(1)).subtract(anyInt(), anyInt());
}
```

The second test always seems to fail on assertions that either content type is not set or the expected result is wrong.

It seems like the response for the first test is somehow being evaluated in the second test and so is obviously wrong!

I know the controller and service work as expected and the exact same tests running with jUnit actually work ok.

I have managed to get the tests to perform properly only when I do the following:

```
 @BeforeGroups("subtract")
 public void reset() {      
    Mockito.reset(calculatorService);
    mockMvc =       MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(calculatorController).build();
 }

 @Test(groups = "subtract")
 public void subtractFunctionTest() throws Exception {    
    System.out.println("***** IN METHOD *****");
    Assert.assertNotNull(calculatorController);
    Result expectedResult = new Result();
    expectedResult.setResult(90);

    when(calculatorService.subtract(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(expectedResult);                                

    //Perform HTTP Get for the homepage
    mockMvc.perform(get("/calculator/subtract").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .param("val1", "100")
    .param("val2", "10"))  
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result", equalTo(90)));    

    //Verify that the service method was only called one time
    verify(calculatorService, times(1)).subtract(anyInt(), anyInt());
}
```

This means I need to add one of these reset methods for each test method though and I then need a group per test method which doesnt seem correct.

Comment: What library do you use for assertions (`Result expectedResult = new Result()`)?

Comment: You're resetting mock after every method, but you don't do anything with `mocMvc`. Can this influence your tests? Can you verify that with changing `@BeforeClass` to `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: Hi Eugen, I tried playing around and no combinations worked. I will update my post with what I have managed to get to work but it would mean a lot of code repetition.

Comment: Library is springs MockMvcResultMatchers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a difference in the behaviour of these frameworks:

- JUnit creates a new instance of class for every of its test methods. This means that the fields are not shared between tests.
- But TestNG creates only one object and thus the state in fields is shared between to `@Test`s

For Mockito you need to init mocks before every test method so that the state is not shared between two `@Test`s in TestNG:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

For JUnit it works out of box because 2nd `@Test` has its own fields and its own mocks.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work, the results of the calls come back in the wrong order. So if my add method expects a result of 5 and my subtract method expects a result of 10, sometimes my add test will fail with an assertion error that it received 10 and expected 5.

Comment: Are you sure you use `@BeforeMethod`, not `@BeforeClass`?

Comment: I tried both BeforeMethod and BeforeClass. The test is making a real call to the controller and mocking the service response so I dont see how the results can be mixed up. The only way I was able to get the tests to work was to use the groups and give each method a group and then reset in the before groups annotation but I will try one more time with the BeforeMethod and come back shortly because I was calling Mockito.reset in an AfterMethod annotation.

Comment: Results :

Failed tests: 
  CalculatorControllerTestNGTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run:175->addFunctionTest:97 JSON path "$.result"
Expected: <31>
     but: was <90>
  CalculatorControllerTestNGTest>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run:175->subtractFunctionTest:118 Content type not set

Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: Its almost as if the first test is kicked off, the response hasnt yet returned from the controller and then second test is kicked off, the mocks are reset and the result of the second test is given to the first test??

Comment: Try removing all of you Before/After stuff, just mark the field as `@Mock` and insert my code - it has to work. You don't run the tests in parallel, right?

Comment: It seems as if the tests are running in parallell yes, is this the default behaviour as I have no specified this.

Comment: For me it worked with `@BeforeMethod` and set the instance that is annotated with `@InjectMocks` to `null` *before* the call of `initMocks()`. See //see https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/issues/304

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, if this answer fits to the questioners problem, because the mocks are not listed. But I'd like to re-state one comment from andy in the accepted answer, which helped me out on the same problem. Here are some more details and an example:

---

```
public class B {

private A a;

B (A a) {
    this.a = a
}

// ...
```

---

```
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    A a;

    @InjectMocks
    B B;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        // ...
        // b.toString();
        // b.getA().toString();
        // a.toString();
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        // ...
        // b.toString();
        // b.getA().toString();
        // a.toString();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void reset()
    {
        // Solution:
        b = null;
    }
}
```

---

Mockitos `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` only re-initializes mocks, as `Mockito.reset(a)` only resets mocks. The problem is the class under test, which is annotated with `@InjectMocks`. This class, here named `B`, is not initialized again. It is initialized for the first test with a mock of `A`, the mock of `A` is re-initialized but `B` still contains the first version of `A`.

The solution is to reset the class under test manually with `b = null` at any plausible place (`@AfterMethod` or before `initMocks`). Then Mockito also re-inizialized the class under test `B`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [MockitoTestNGListener](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-testng) it is similar to `JUnit` `MockitoJUnitRunner` or  `MockitoExtension`.

Example of code:

```
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.testng.MockitoTestNGListener;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Map;

@Listeners(MockitoTestNGListener.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    Map map;

    @InjectMocks
    SomeType someType;

    @Test
    void test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```