# Method inside "When" actually being called

Tags: mockito, testng

When I am testing a class A (TestNG) which uses some methods from some other class Helper Class
I am mocking the helper class(Mockito) for testing class A.
but when(helper.methodUsedByClassA(value)).thenReturn(new HashMap>())
this line of code is actually calling helper.methodUsedByClassA and a null pointer exception is thrown (because of data I am using for testing is not valid)

why is this happening? Why would the method name inside mockito "when" actually be called ?

```
class ATest{

@Mock
private Helper helper;

private A target;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.target = new UpdateDigicatKdpAsinUtil(helper);
}


@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void testMethod(List<String> value) {

    when(helper.methodUsedByClassA(value)).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, List<String>>({{put("test", new ArrayList<>())}}));

}


@DataProvider
public Object[][] data(){
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
   return new Object[][]
   {

     {list}

   }

}
```

```
class Helper{

     public Map<String, List<String>> methoUsedByClassA(int value) {
          //This method is being executed because it is mentioned inside "when"
}



}
```

Comment: There seem to be some compilation issues and typos with the example you provided. What is the `put` method you mention? Your `value` is a `List<String>` while your method exepcts an `int`. If I fix/remove those issues I have no problem running that test in `TestNG` (using `testng 7.0.0`, mockito `2.28.2`). If you use different versions please mention them in your question.

Comment: It might also help if you can provide the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get an NPE because helper is NULL.

The problem is that the @Mock annotation isn't processed and because of that, the variable helper isn't initialized.

You have to annotate the test class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class). MockitoJUnitRunner will process the @Mock annotation and create the mock.

Comment: In testng you have to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` together with `@BeforeMethod` instead, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591644/using-mockito-with-testng)

Comment: @second You are right. I missed MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
With that line, you don't need to use MockitoJUnitRunner.class
But if the real method from the mocked class would be called then the variable helper is probably not referencing a mock or the method being called is final which makes it impossible for the mock to override it. Time to use a debugger and step through the test.